# getting seances related to a user from his auth token in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt

I want to display seances as a response, but when I do the request and I send x-access-tokens through postman, it sends me an error message id not defined. for me I want to pass the id of the authenticated user as a parameter to get seances related to it in source code.

And here's my source code.

my seances.routes.js:

```
const controller = require('../controllers/seance.controller');

const authJwt = require('../middleware/authJwt');

module.exports = function(app) {
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "x-access-token, Origin, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});

app.post(
  "/api/admin/seance",
  [

  ],
  controller.createSeance
  );
  app.get(
    "/api/etudiant/seance",
    [
      authJwt.verifyToken,
      authJwt.isEtudiant
    ],
    controller.afficherSeancesEtudiant
    );
```

};

and authJwt.js:

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const config = require("../config/auth.config.js");
const db = require("../models");   
const User = db.user;

verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
  let token = req.headers["x-access-token"];

  if (!token) {
    return res.status(403).send({
    message: "No token provided!"
  });
}

 jwt.verify(token, config.secret, (err, decoded) => {
 if (err) {
  return res.status(401).send({
    message: "Unauthorized!"
  });
  }
 req.id = decoded.id;
 next();
});
};
```

and here's my seances.controller.js related to get seances to etudiant:

```
exports.afficherSeancesEnseignant = async (req,res) => {

try{
    const enseignant = await Enseignant.findOne({where: {userId:id}});

    const matricule = enseignant.matricule;

    Seance.findAll({
        where: {
            enseignant: matricule,
        }
    }).then((data) => {
        res.status(200).send(data);
    }).catch(e => {
        res.status(500).send({message: e.message});
    })


}catch(e){
    res.status(500).send({
        message: e.message
    })       
}
}
```

for the postman requests:
[image: response returned]

for the Auth I used jwt, for me I want to pass the authenticated user id as a parameter, and get related seances to it, and for the technologies I used express.js and node.js.

Comment: You mean `{where: {userId: req.id}}`, right?

Comment: yeah, but I didn't know how I will get that req.id, the way that will help me to get it, I'm not using passport.js for authentification.

Comment: I did some job in authJwt.js and I used it seances.routes.js, but passing it made me a little trouble.

Comment: The `req.id` is filled in the `verifyToken` middleware, isn't it?